# jQueryUI dialog, is it possible to use your own buttons instead the one generated by dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a modal form that is pretty much same as this one: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-form.html

The form already has a submit button there. I can manage to use this button to submit the form, but the callback function won't work. Is there a way to use my own submit button and make the callback function working?

```js
buttons: {
    "Create an account": function () {            
        $("#dialog-form").html("thank you for <b>submit</a>");
    },
    Cancel: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
}
```

**you can test my code on jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/QSJpS/3/

Comment: What callback function? Do just want to close the form after you click your button? Why don't you just call $("#dialog-form").dialog("close"); in your button click handler?

Comment: $("#dialog-form").html("thank you for <b>submit</a>");

Comment: Could you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and demonstrate your issue?

Comment: I want to show "thank you" message to replace the form in the modal dialog. just let them know account is created.

Comment: scott, I don't think I can get it work in jsFiddle.  in my code, I have $.get('/home/post', function (data), I dont know how to create "/home/post" file in jsFiddle,   I will upload my code to github.

Comment: @feelexit - Why don't you post the markup of the form you are retriveing through `$.get`?

Comment: that just a simple form with one submit button.  I moved the form to the main file, now it just  one file.  you can see all the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/QSJpS/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Here's a working jsFiddle demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/2SV6R/)***

The part I changed was inside of the "Create an account" section:

```
if ( bValid ) {
    $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" ); 
    $( this ).html("Thank you!");
}
```

### Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT for Ajax Solution:

What you need to do is post your form via ajax so that you don't have a page refresh screwing up your message. You can do something like this:

```
$("#submit-button-id").click(function(e) {

    var data = 'name='+ $("#name").val() + 
               '&email=' + $("#email").val() + 
               '&password=' + $("#password").val() ;  

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "some-processing-page.html",  
        data: data,  
        success: function() {  
            $('#dialog-form').html("Thank you for your submission!");  
            $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").hide();
        }  
    });  

    e.preventDefault();  

});
```

Comment: thank you. but thats not what I need. I want to use my own button if it's possible. just upload my code to jsFiddle, Can you take a look? http://jsfiddle.net/QSJpS/3/

Comment: @feelexit - I know it's not exactly what you are asking, but it demonstrates via the original example how to replace the text. What your problem is, is that you are trying to submit the form which posts everything back to the server. You shouldn't submit the form via a submit button, rather, submit the form via an ajax post w/ callback where you could then change the text.

Comment: thank you so much, I was confused by regular submit and ajax submit.  I just used .post when user clicks on the submit button.  .post will trigger the callback function after form is successfully posted.

Comment: @feelexit - No problem at all. [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is simply the shorthand method for the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method I used in the answer.  So it's exactly the same thing.  Glad it works for you =D

Answer (score 0):

So, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/QSJpS/4/?

```
$(function(){
    $("#submitButton").click(function () {

                    var bValid = true;

                    if (bValid) {
                        $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + $("#name").val() + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + $("#email").val() + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + $("#password").val() + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>");
                        $("#dialog-form").html("thank you for <b>submit</a>");
                        $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").hide();
                    }
     });
});               
​
```